# How to prompt user to input the time in a specific format?

Tags: python, html, flask

I was wondering if there's a way to ask the user to input the time in a single input bar following the specific format for datetime, so the user will have no choice but to use the specified format.

Like this:

[image]

Comment: You could use a date/datetime input field. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

Comment: The one for datetime is not supported in any browser yet apparently! In the worst case scenario, I will have to use 2 input boxes, one for date and the other for time and and combine both of them. Other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) is a plugin for jquery if your project has one

```
$("#date").mask("9999-99-99 99:99:99");
```

You can use [dateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/2.5.3) for checking date serverside

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

def is_date(string):
    try:
        parse(string)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.

Comment: Thank you for answer. This is actually really good, but I was looking for it in html.

Comment: Fixed. I don't think here is any crossbrowser solution for that in HTML